# Extending BaseRequest to make custom post request

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying to make custom post request with `BrowserClient (package:http/browser_client.dart)` using send method. I don`t understand how should i extend abstract BaseRequest, should i override finalize method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're doing something very custom, you want to use one of the subclasses of the abstract [BaseRequest](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/http/0.11.3%2B16/http/BaseRequest-class.html) class (seen in the docs under *Implemented by*).

I'm almost sure you want to just use the [Request](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/http/0.11.3%2B16/http/Request-class.html) class, like so:

```
var client = new BrowserClient();
var request = new Request("post", Uri.parse("http://example.com"));
// ... set up the request some more ...
var response = await client.send(request);
// ... do stuff with response ...
```